restar un mes y unos dias a fecha dada
Hola como estan un excelente usuario de este foro con el nombre jachguate me ayudo a realizar este codigo el cual lo que hace es adicionar a una fecha dada los meses que le ponga en una casilla, todo funciona perfecto, pero ahora recurro nuevamente para hacer que en otro campo tipo date preaviso se reste a la hora final que da el script menos un mes y menos 10 dias... es decir
este es el codigo que llevo y que he estado modificando pero me resta son dos meses y no doy con lo de los dias a esta nueva fecha:
<p>Meses:
  <input type="number" name="meses" id="meses" min="1" max="12" onchange = "calcularFin()">
  <br>
  Fecha Inicial
  <input type="date" id="fechainicial" onchange="calcularFin()"/>
  <br>
  Fecha fin: 
  <input type="date" id="fechafinal"/>
</p>
<p>Fecha Preaviso:
  <input type="date" id="preaviso"/>
</p>
<script>
const imeses = document.getElementById('meses');
const ifechainicial = document.getElementById('fechainicial');
const ifechafinal = document.getElementById('fechafinal');
const ifpreaviso = document.getElementById('preaviso');

function calcularFin() {
  let meses = parseInt(imeses.value);
  let fechaini = ifechainicial.valueAsDate;
  let fechafin = ifechafinal.valueAsDate;
  ifechafinal.valueAsDate = new Date(fechaini.setMonth(fechaini.getMonth()+meses));
  ifpreaviso.valueAsDate = new Date(fechafin.setMonth(fechafin.getMonth()-1));

}

ifechainicial.valueAsDate = new Date();
calcularFin();
</script>


Hay un tema con los UTC que lo expliqué en tu otra pregunta, si te vas a la documentación de Date vas a ver al lado izquierdo las multimples funciones que tiene, por ejemplo:

getFullYear() / getUTCFullYear() -> Obtener el año

setFullYear() / setUTCFullYear() -> setear el año

getMonth() / getUTCMonth() -> Obtener el mes

setMonth() / setUTCMonth() -> setear el mes

getDate() / getUTCDate() -> Obtener el día

setDate() / setUTCDate() -> setear el día


Para sumar "algo" a la fecha actual es siempre la misma lógica
new Date(fecha.setAlgo(fecha.getAlgo() + algo);

Es decir, obtenemos la magnitud, le sumamos ese "algo", lo seteamos a la fecha y creamos una nueva fecha con esos datos. Es un lio tremendo, pero es siempre igual.
Entonces para sumar días (date)
new Date(fecha.setUTCDate(fecha.getUTCDate() + dias);



const imeses = document.getElementById('meses');
const ifechainicial = document.getElementById('fechainicial');
const ifechafinal = document.getElementById('fechafinal');
const ifpreaviso = document.getElementById('preaviso');

function calcularFin() {
  let meses =  imeses.valueAsNumber;
  let fechaini = ifechainicial.valueAsDate;
  let fechafin = new Date(fechaini.setUTCMonth(fechaini.getUTCMonth()+meses));
  
  fechafinal.valueAsDate = fechafin;
  const menosUnmes = new Date(fechafin.setUTCMonth(fechafin.getMonth()-1));
  ifpreaviso.valueAsDate = new Date(menosUnmes.setUTCDate(menosUnmes.getUTCDate()-10));

}

ifechainicial.valueAsDate = new Date();
calcularFin();
<p>Meses:
  <input type="number" name="meses" id="meses" min="1" max="12" onchange = "calcularFin()">
  <br>
  Fecha Inicial
  <input type="date" id="fechainicial" onchange="calcularFin()"/>
  <br>
  Fecha fin: 
  <input type="date" id="fechafinal" readonly/>
</p>
<p>Fecha Preaviso:
  <input type="date" id="preaviso" readonly/>
</p>




en la fecha Preaviso sigue saliendo el mismo mes de la fecha fin y debe ser un mes menos los días si están pero el mes sale igual al mes de la fecha fin

@Eduardo Por eso te explicaba la logica, para que pudieras ajustar el tema tu gusto. En todo caso ya incluí el código que resta un mes a la respuesta
