Calculo en fechas dependiendo los meses y fecha inicial
Hace unos dias un miembro de esta Comunidad me ayudó a realizar un proyecto en JS el cual calculaba las fechas finales a partir de los meses la fecha final se calculaba pero no caimos en cuenta que el dia aveces variaba por los dias no labolares por lo que me gsutaria que a este script que el me ayudo, solo muestre el mes y el año y deje el campo dia del input date vacio para agregarlo manualmente.
Los campos fecha inicial, fecha fin y fecha preaviso dependen del calculo que se haga en el campo duración donde se agrega un numero (meses) pero que lo siga haciendo tal cual como este en el script, solo que no calcule los días pues como dije estos varían por los días No laborales y para evitar errores mejor se agregan manualmente...
<input style="width: 120px;" name="fechainicial" type="date" id="fechainicial" size="60" max="9999-12-31" class="validar" onChange = "calcularFin()" required>

Este es el el script...
<script>
    const imeses = document.getElementById('duracion');
    const ifechainicial = document.getElementById('fechainicial');
    const ifechafinal = document.getElementById('fechafinal');
    const ifpreaviso = document.getElementById('fechapreaviso');
    
    function calcularFin() {
      let meses =  imeses.valueAsNumber;
      let fechaini = ifechainicial.valueAsDate;
      let fechafin = new Date(fechaini.setUTCMonth(fechaini.getUTCMonth()+meses));
      
      fechafinal.valueAsDate = fechafin;
      const menosUnmes = new Date(fechafin.setUTCMonth(fechafin.getMonth()-1));
      ifpreaviso.valueAsDate = new Date(menosUnmes.setUTCDate(menosUnmes.getUTCDate()-10));
    
    }
    
    ifechainicial.valueAsDate = new Date();
    calcularFin();
</script>

este es el hilo de la entrada del post
restar un mes y unos dias a fecha dada

Tendriamos que ver que fue lo que esa persona te ayuda a hacer, ya que en lo que has compartido esta bastante enrredado y el html le faltan cosas, tambien deberias argumentar que has intentado hacer... ya que hasta donde persivo estas esperando que te hagan la tarea ... y los chicos de la comunidad suelen ver mal eso ...

en este enlace es donde se da solución solo hacerle esa modificación.. no calcular el día ya que este varia https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/621713/restar-un-mes-y-unos-dias-a-fecha-dada/621715?noredirect=1#comment1093478_621715

Según el código de esa maravillosa respuesta, basta con quitar el readonly del input para que puedas editar el día a gusto

la fecha se puede editar sin problemas, lo que no se quiere es que al hacer el calculo  lo haga como esta pero que omita el día (en los input fecha) no haga el calculo del día solo el mes como esta y año como esta... pues al mostrar el día crea confusión...

Para aclarar, tu estas diciendo que: Quieres un input donde puedas editar solo la parte día, pero el mes y año queden estáticos?? y cual sería el input que se tiene que comportar así?

Hola Yussef pues los mismos campos que alli estan fechafinal y fechapreaviso los cuales calculan la fecha dependiendo de la fechainicial y duración.. eso lo hace bien todo.. lo que quiero es que en el calculo que hace saque el del dia no haga el dia solo muestre asi como esta Mes y Año el cual lo hace perfecto, pero el dia que lo deje vacio o no lo calcule.

Debes agregar una @ al nombre cuando te refieras a alguien, así llega una alerta. Aun no me queda claro, tú quieres que en el campo preaviso muestre, por ejemplo: __-09-2024 y que el usuario solo pueda editar el día?

@Yussef perfectamente así.. pero en el código que envío JavaScript no se como poner para que omita hacer el calculo con el día.. saludos

para evitar errores mejor se agregan manualmente..., creo que se pueden cometer más errores al hacerlo manualmente que programando una rutina que tome en cuenta este caso particular, Pero claro, esta sólo es mi humilde opinión.

Para que un input[date] te permita solo seleccionar el día correspondiente en un mes, debes asignar los atributos max y min, los cuales deben estar dentro del mes en cuestión.
El formato debe ser yyyy-MM-dd, y para obtener esos datos puedes realizar un split al retorno de la función toISOString(), que retorna algo del estilo de: 2011-10-05T14:48:00.000Z


const imeses = document.getElementById('meses');
const ifechainicial = document.getElementById('fechainicial');
const ifechafinal = document.getElementById('fechafinal');
const ifpreaviso = document.getElementById('preaviso');

function calcularFin() {
  const meses =  imeses.valueAsNumber;
  const fechaini = ifechainicial.valueAsDate;
  if(!meses || !fechaini ) return;
  
  const fechafin = new Date(fechaini.setUTCMonth(fechaini.getUTCMonth()+meses)); 
  setMinMaxFecha(fechafin,fechafinal); 

  const menosUnmes = new Date(fechafin.setUTCMonth(fechafin.getMonth()-1));
  setMinMaxFecha(menosUnmes,ifpreaviso); 


}

function setMinMaxFecha(fecha, input){
  fecha = new Date(fecha);
  let parts = fecha.toISOString().split("-");
  const min = `${parts[0]}-${parts[1]}-01`
 
  fecha.setUTCMonth(fecha.getUTCMonth()+1);
  fecha.setUTCDate(0);
  parts = fecha.toISOString().split("T")[0].split("-");
  const max = `${parts[0]}-${parts[1]}-${parts[2]}`
 
  input.value = "";
  input.max = max;
  input.min = min;
}

calcularFin();
<p>Meses:
  <input type="number" name="meses" id="meses" min="1" max="12" onchange = "calcularFin()">
  <br>
  Fecha Inicial
  <input type="date" id="fechainicial" onchange="calcularFin()"/>
  <br>
  Fecha fin: 
  <input type="date" id="fechafinal" />
</p>
<p>Fecha Preaviso:
  <input type="date" id="preaviso"/>
</p>




excelente lo hace en la fecha Preaviso, también debería hacerlo en la fecha Fin en que parte del código lo hace y obvio hay que quitar el readonly para poder agregar manualmente el día a Fecha Fin? asi como esta pero que en fecha fin el dia salga por ejemplo __-09-2024

otra cosa como hago para que no muestre la fecha actual en el campo fecha inicial al cargar el form

@Eduardo A ver prueba ahora

Yussef ocurre algo probando el codigo por ejemplo coloco en el campo Meses el numero 3 y en fecha inicial 01/06/2024 y cuando el dia es 01 en fecha inicial no aparece mes en los campos fin y presaviso... solo aparece el año.. sera algo con el dia 01 inicial.. por que al poner dia 02 en inicial si hace el calculo normal como se quiere en los campos fin y preaviso...

@Eduardo El problema era que utilicé getMonth en lugar de getUTCMonth, y tiene relación con lo que te comentaba en una respuesta anterior que te di. Esta corregido

Excelente no sabes como me has salvado... tenia que estar sacando manualmente el conteo de los meses algo tedioso... otra cosa por que los campos fin y preaviso aparecen deshabilitados por si toca cambiar le mes calculado no deja muy a pesar de estar un campo habilitado...??

@Eduardo Que bueno te haya servido, no entendi tu pregunta- > "no deja muy a pesar de estar un campo habilitado" ??

por ejemplo sabes que muchas veces a pesar de calcular el mes aveces toca escribirlo manual (dias festivos hacen que toque correr el mes) son pocos los casos pero aqui haciendo algunos noto que en el campo fechafin y fecha preaviso estan inhabilitados la seccion mes.. por si toca en estos casos ponerlo manual el mes solo en estos casos

El truco se basa en restringir el input con un max y min, puedes variar los rangos para obtener más o menos días habilitados.  Este tipo de asunto lo vivo todos los días: Mi cliente me dice "haz esto y que cumpla X reglas", lo entrego, pero luego resulta que según sea el caso esa regla no aplica. Y te responderé lo que le respondo ellos: Si las reglas no aplican, mejor dejemos lo campos abiertos y que escriban cualquier cosa, es menos trabajo para todos

entiendo.. mil gracias por tu ayuda y excelente.. una lastima el código era lo que necesitaba... y tener que no usarlo Dueleeeee jejejeje
